# Setting snapping in QGIS 3.24 for specific layers using QgsSnappingConfig.addLayers

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, snapping

I am trying to set the snappings for certain layers in my map.

I can do it for one layer but not for a list of layers. Here is my code:

```
layerPole = None
layersPole = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pole')

layerAdrs = None
layersAdrs = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('adrs')

if layersPole:
    layerPole = layersPole[0]
    
if layersAdrs:
    layerAdrs = layersAdrs[0]

tolerance = 10

snap_config = QgsSnappingConfig()
snap_config.setEnabled(True)
snap_config.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.Vertex)
snap_config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels) # ProjectUnits: 2/Pixels: 1/LayerUnits: 0
snap_config.setTolerance(tolerance)
snap_config.setIntersectionSnapping(True)
snap_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.SnappingMode.AdvancedConfiguration)
# snap_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.AllLayers)
# lyr_settings = QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(True, QgsSnappingConfig.SnappingType.Vertex, tolerance, QgsTolerance.Pixels)
# snap_config.setIndividualLayerSettings(layerPole, lyr_settings)
snap_config.addLayers(layerPole, layerAdrs)
QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(snap_config)

print("done")
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: QgsSnappingConfig.addLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'
```

How to achieve my task:

Also, I would like to know how to reset all the snapping settings which have been altered by my code?

Comment: you should add an iterable instead of individual layers. e.g.
snap_config.addLayers([layerPole, layerAdrs])

Comment: I can't find reset for snapping settings. You can save actual settings and restore them when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the layers to a list and I iterated over the list, but still the error TypeError: QgsSnappingConfig.addLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer'

Answer (score 1):

By chance I found this link:

https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/qgis.core/QgsSnappingUtils/setConfig/python-qgssnappingutils-setconfig-method-examples.html

I did not use `addLayers`, but set the individual snapping settings to the snapping configuration and then add it to `QgsProject.instance`

My code ended up like this:

```
layerPole = None
layersPole = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('pole')

layerAdrs = None
layersAdrs = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('adrs')


if layersPole:
    layerPole = layersPole[0]
    print(type(layerPole))
if layersAdrs:
    layerAdrs = layersAdrs[0]
    print(type(layerAdrs))

tolerance = 10

snap_config = QgsSnappingConfig()
snap_config.setEnabled(True)
snap_config.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.Vertex)
snap_config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels) #ProjectUnits 2/Pixels 1/LayerUnits 0
snap_config.setTolerance(tolerance)
snap_config.setIntersectionSnapping(True)
snap_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.SnappingMode.AdvancedConfiguration)
lyr_settings = QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(True, QgsSnappingConfig.SnappingType.Vertex, tolerance, QgsTolerance.Pixels)
snap_config.setIndividualLayerSettings(layerPole, lyr_settings)
snap_config.setIndividualLayerSettings(layerAdrs, lyr_settings)
QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(snap_config)

print("done")
```