# QGIS 3.10 PyQGIS Snapping node tool not showing despite snapping settings active

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, snapping

I was able to set the snapping to the two point layers of interest, as I indicated in the following question

[Setting snapping in QGIS 3.24 for specific layers using QgsSnappingConfig.addLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451817/setting-snapping-in-qgis-3-24-for-specific-layers-using-qgssnappingconfig-addlay)

In my code I activate the snapping apparently successfully, the horseshoe appears pressed, however when I start adding features with my map tool, the cursor node tool that indicates the snapping is activated, is not showing, and what matters more than the appearance of the cursor, is the fact that my line layer is not snapping at all to the point layers.

I am not including code because I do not know which part should I include.

The map tool works smoothly and add lines, just not snapped.

What could be the reason?

I noticed that if I start editing normally in QGIS, and click the add feature button, then the node tool shows up.

Comment: You can set snapping for individual/active/all layers, you may try to snap to a layer the snapping is not active for.

Comment: Zoltan, I am sorry I do not understand what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295309/activating-snapping-with-pyqgis/355250#355250 to see how to adapt your map tool to make use of the snapping settings, because it doesn't happen automagically.

Comment: Thank you Ben, I just wanted to know that I will try to descipher that answer that one can say is very well elaborated but quite difficult for me, because i really thought it was just the snapping settings, as you cleverly said 'automagically'.

Comment: It's really very straight forward... I put another little example here: https://gist.github.com/benwirf/7c47ca5ac4ada69661aeda20b456102f

Comment: Thanks Ben, your answer is correct, now I can snap to my points, it was not easy because I have some drawing tools in one class and others in another (because I am adapting an existing code to my requirements). It works but my line before snapping is not visible. Maybe you should instead of comment, answer the question to be able to accept the solution.